# Disabling macro followed by block

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor

With a macro such as `assert()`, I can define it like `#define assert(_expr_) (void)0`, to make it so that it gets removed on compilation, and the compiler doesn't try to evaluate its argument.

---

But I have a macro that is meant to be followed by a function body block. In this case it is part of a unit testing framework, and evaluates to a member function definition of a class, like:

```
#define TEST(_name_) void TestFixtureUniqueName(_name_)::Run(Argument& argument)
```

so the compiler will expect it to be followed by the `{ ... }` function body block. And inside it, it references variables that are defined in this scope (members of the class, and arguments).

---

Is there a quick and easy way to disable such a macro in a similar way as `assert()` above, such that the compiler will not even try to compile the following block, so that it doesn't matter if it contains syntax errors or undefined symbols?

Currently I'm doing something like

```
#define TEST(_name_) static void __NeverRun##_name_(MemberType1& m_member1, MemberType2& m_member2, Argument& argument)
```

it is just for use during debugging/refactoring, not for production code

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What problem are you trying to solve by removing `TEST` macro?

Comment: a simple way to temporarily remove most of the `TEST() {...}` blocks, without going through many files and lines of code.

Comment: If removing files from project altogether (i.e., CMake code that builds or not specified files) is not an option, then I guess what you have is the least effort way.

Comment: Can't really answer without knowing more about `TestFixtureUniqueName` and how that class is defined.

Comment: Even if the function definition is magically "disabled", where do you expect the definition of the function should come from?  Is it an override in a derived class? Does this code appear inside a class at all?  Presumably the header declares `void TestFixtureUniqueName(_name_)::Run(Argument& argument)` already, and omitting the definition will cause a linker error.  You can use `#define TEST(_name_) void CompletelyUniqueName(_name_)` and let the linker discard the function, (provided there are no syntax errors) but this doesn't address the now-missing definition of the function.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a quick and easy way to disable such a macro in a similar way as assert() above, such that the compiler will not even try to compile the following block, so that it doesn't matter if it contains syntax errors or undefined symbols?

No. Enclose the whole function definition inside `#ifdef`.

You can put the whole function definition inside macro definition which expands to nothing when not running tests.

```
#if run_tests
#define TEST(_name_, ...) void TestFixtureUniqueName(_name_)::Run(Argument& argument) __VA_ARGS__
#else
#define TEST(_name_, ...)
#endif

TEST(_name_,
{
   int i = 13;
   foo();
}
)
```

But overall, using ^ such macros quickly becomes unmaintainable and unreadable. Consider not using any macros at all and just writing it out and just enclosing function definitions inside a simple `#ifdef`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enclose the function's code in `#ifdef` block. Care should be taken that after pre-processing stage, the final output should be syntactically correct.

Comment: The problem is to remove code following the macro call. E.g., there would be `TEST(X) { int i = 13; foo(); }`, solution should allow this to compile even if `TEST` should not exist.

Comment: Ah, in that case, the whole of function definition needs to be encompassed inside the `#ifdef` block.